# Angular: how to inject a few static pre-rendered pages without need to turn-on SSR

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I'm planning to create a game in a browser and Angular seems like a good fit for it.

Though, I do want my site to be SEO-friendly, at least some pages. Also, I'd like to allow fast loading for some pages loading that don't have lots of logic (landing page, about page, etc.).

I thought about using SSR, but it seems like it has a decent number of draw-backs: lots of extra files on the server, plus extra server load to generate those pages. I did not do research and not sure how really big the problem SSR causes on the server. But while I'm prototyping SSR I'd like to explore alternatives.

Is it possible to achieve this in Angular without using SSR? Specifically, I'd like to generate a few static pages, tell angular to navigate to those pages when they are referenced, and for the rest use normal Angular routing.

Thanks!

P.S. I've tried to google, but can't find anything that tells this is possible, so I assume this is not a good option. But I think it is worth asking.

Comment: There is a very good tool, that can create some prerenderd pages, but you have to create an SSR application to achieve this. Check this article: https://medium.com/swlh/prerender-angular-application-be-seo-ae1183c621cb

Comment: I don't have a subscription to medium. Could you describe the high-level idea? Though, I guess I'll just stay with SSR

Comment: https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/blob/master/schematics/universal/README.md#prerender-angular-app